# Qt based program: Memory usage continues to grow

Tags: linux, memory, qt4.7

I use `top` to check the memory usage of My own program , it continues to increase , until my swap space started to be in use.

It's not like a memory leak ,  because when I close my program , the memory usage drops down immediately.

How should I find out where the problem is ?

Thanks !

Comment: "It's not like a memory leak , because when I close my program, the memory usage drops down immediately" -- well, when you close the program your OS will free the memory it used. This has nothing to do with whether or not there's a memory leak. I'm sure you have one.

Comment: The memory usage should drop when closing the program because the OS will clean up any memory that was not cleaned up by the program itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely a memory leak. Use Valgrind, for example, to analyze your code (http://www.cprogramming.com/debugging/valgrind.html).